# Google Maps - Avoid motorways only on part of route

Tags: google-maps

Planning a route in Google Maps, I am trying to create a route which is part motorways, part country roads (i.e. not motorways). Say, for example, that I want to create route "A --> B --> C", and I want to go from A to B using motorways, but from B to C I want to avoid motorways. Is there any way to do that in Google Maps - or at least in another platform?